# hook for maintenance mode

Tags: 7, maintenance-mode

I would like to send an email to some users, when i put my Drupal-7 website in maintenance mode. Are there any hooks that allow me to do this? I could not figure it out for myself.

Comment: If you're enabling maintenance mode through the UI you can use `hook_form_alter` and add a submit handler which sends the email. If by drush/something else, you'd probably need to script it as part of that op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Clive said you can use [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x) or [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7.x) and add extra submit handler to send email notifications.

```
function YOURMODULE_form_system_site_maintenance_mode_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  $form['#submit'][] = 'email_system_settings_form_submit';
}

function email_system_settings_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Add your email code here
}
```